# Is it possible to pass variables to the top-level makefile from sub makefile?

Tags: makefile

I know that `export` is used to pass the value of a variable recursively downwards from top-level Makefile to sub Makefiles. However, if I need to pass variables upwards, what should I do?

The side-effect of modifying an exported variable seems to be cleared after the sub Makefile is processed. I tried to export it in the sub Makefile, but it does not work.

For example, I need to collect the object files that the sub Makefile generated in the variable `L1`.

Top-level Makefile

```
$(info Top-level makefile)

export L1 = one.obj

sub1:
  cd sub1; make

all: sub1
  $(info $(L1))
```

Sub makefile: `sub1/Makefile`

```
$(info sub makefile)

L1 += two.obj
export L1

all:
  $(info want to pass to the top-level: $(L1))
```

I expect that `L1` contains `one.obj` and `two.obj` when target `all` builds. However, it only has `one.obj`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The short answer is no. Could you tell us *why* you want to do this?

Comment: Instead, you could have `rules.mk` on a top level with the build rules, and lower-level `Makefile` would `include` it and build a specific binary.